# Update imports after copying a project in Eclipse (but not deleting old project)

Tags: java, eclipse, import, ide

I have a `Java` project in `Eclipse` called `project_a` which I copied to `project_b`. Both projects are now identical except for the `package project_a` in `project_a`'s preamble and `package project_b` in `project_b`'s preamble.

However, in both projects there are classes that `import` other classes from sub-folders within that project (e.g. the folder directory and class file: `project_a.some_folder.ClassA`). The issue is that in `project_b`, all imports refer to `project_a` (e.g. the preamble of a class in `project_b` will typically read `import project_a.some_folder.ClassA`).

I want to update all `import`s in `project_b` such that it's now (for example `import project_b.some_folder.ClassA`).

How do I do this?

Comment: You shouldnt copy the Projects. Export them and import them, then you dont get that problems.

Comment: @kai Great to know. But it's too late now :)

Comment: @user2763361 Take a look a the `.classpath` file in your project's directory. You can edit this file (outside eclipse!) with any ascii editor.

Comment: If you copied the project folder from 'project_a' in which you have the package called 'project_a', then afterwards you will have a new project folder 'project_b' with the same package 'project_a'. From now on you can simply rename this package. The refactoring toll in Eclipse will do the rest (like adjusting all import statements).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Well what happens if the `import` didn't update? I now have a `project_a` and `project_b` after copying it and all imports are still to `project_a`. Just want to know how to fix this one.

Comment: Is there anything misunderstanding in: "From now on you can simply rename this package. The refactoring tool in Eclipse will do the rest (like adjusting all import statements)."?